# CSS :hover state not triggering in IE10 + IE11

Tags: css, hover, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

Currently I'm working on a HTML5/CSS3 valid webapplication that is responding fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE9. I have several buttons on a page and all have a hoverstate that change the background-color from white to blue. Now when I view this page in IE10/IE11 when initially hovering over a button element the background doesnt change (in other words; browser isnt triggering my CSS rules).

When inspecting the element using the IE11DEV tools and forcing :hover (through [a:] button), again the background doesnt change (However I can see my :hover CSS property!)

- When I resize the #wrapper element (through changing CSS width) or my browserwindow, suddenly everything starts to respond..
- Also I've found several fixes that forces the browser to redraw and
  then ofcourse I see my :hover states.

**I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require a redraw (or JS/ browser specific JS)**

Any suggestions/solutions would be very much appreciated :-)

Please see the following screenshot of me forcing a hover, literally hovering over the button, and the CSS that is supposed to be displayed
(cant post inline image, reputation too low)
 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Xvu.png

Thanks in advance,

Kind regards,
Jasper

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: Make sure the browser isn't displaying the page in compatibility mode.